# Filter column by dropdown-values using DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I´m using the DataTables-plug (version 1.10.12) to display a table on my website.
One column of the table, called "status", contains a dropdown-field with, like:

```
<tr>
<td>
...
    <select name="dropdown_status" id="139">
      <option value="-1">canceled</option>
      <option value="1" selected>open</option>
      <option value="2">in work</option>
      <option value="3">waiting</option>
      <option value="4">closed</option>
    </select>
...
</td>
</tr>
```

I want to filter by that `status`-column, e.g, show only rows that have the selected status `closed`. 
The default filtering doesn´t work on such content of course, because it´s not plain text that needs to be filtered, but html-code that needs to be stripped.
I have tried different approaches with selectors, the DataTables rendering- and searchfunction. I´m very new to JavaScript, AJAX, JQuery and DataTables and i´m running out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need milti-filter select like in this example: [link](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

Comment: sysquare: thank you for your comment, but i don´t see where this example helps me. The example filters plain text, but i guess i need to strip my column-content somehow.

Answer (score 0):

JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

HTML code:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Include these datatable jquery files:

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, that doesn´t solve the problem (i already had that same code): The dropdownfield for the status-column i want to filter has the same value multiple times and the filtering doesn´t work. The result is empty every time i want to filter that column, resulting in an empty table.

Comment: While  I have the same code working fine, on my exact same requirement as yours. You may need to debug javascript code, there must be something wrong there only.

Comment: can you show me your code please? especially the table column with the filterarble dropdownfield.

Comment: Cant paste it here. Character limit. However, mine is JSP Java spring based code.